# How to count entries with ajax and rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to create an ajax for the counting of my `notifications` that have not been read yet.

So far I have this all working just not the ajax part.. i have to reload the page to see the updated count.  I would like the count to automatically update without the reloading of the page.

_navbar.html.erb

```html
<% if current_user.notifications.where(read: false).count > 0 %>
        <div style="width:15px;height:15px;border:solid #00ccff 1px;background-color:#00ccff;border-radius:4px;float:right;margin-top:20px;margin-left:-15px;">
        <div style="padding:2px;margin-top:-6px;">
           <h style="color:white;"> <%= current_user.notifications.where(read: false).count %> </h>
        </div>
          
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

What do i need to do to make this count without reloading the page using ajax? I know i need to make a `_navbar.js.erb` I just don't know what I would put in there to `replace` the count with the new updated one that was just submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Create an endpoint which just returns the notification for the current user.

```
class NotificationsController
  def index
    @notifications = current_user.notifications
    render json: @notifications
  end
end
```

Then you will need to write a function in a JS file.

Then if you have `jQuery` already available then in make a method which will be called something on this line:

```
    $.ajax(
      {url: '/notifications'}
    ).done(function (result) {
      // set the notification to the dom element from here
      window.setTimeout(this.loadSyncStatus, 5000);
    })
```